# Overwriting methods in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a gem in my rails app, and there is a method that I would like to override. The gam is [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic), and the specific method I was to override is [find_by_smart_case_login_field(login)](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/login.rb#L106).

I made a file in `lib/modules` with the following code:

```
# lib/modules/login.rb
module Authlogic
  module ActsAsAuthentic
    module Login
      module Config
        def find_by_smart_case_login_field(login)
          login = login.downcase unless validates_uniqueness_of_login_field_options[:case_sensitive] 

          if login_field
            where({ login_field.to_sym => login })
          else
            where({ email_field.to_sym => login })
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But this didn't do anything. Does anyone know how to overwrite the above method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are monkey patching a gem. Not bad, just don't abuse it:)

Two things you need to do before making your monkey patching works.

1. Add `/lib` to auto load path otherwise Rails don't know it.

   In `config/application.rb`, find the `autoload_path` line, change it to

   ```
   config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras #{config.root}/lib)
   ```
2. Require your custom module at app loading.

   In `config/initializers`, add a custom file say `application.rb`, then add the following line

   ```
   require 'modules/login.rb'
   # Pay attention: No "lib/" before the file path
   ```

Now, profit!

As to module path, it doesn't matter as long as your module nesting is correct in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here, but my guess would be that you'd have to name the file something like

```
lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/login/config.rb
```

In other words, I believe the path has to map to the module structure.

Comment: Also, you may want to temporarily toss in a `raise "foo"` or something like that, just to be sure that the problem is that your code isn't being exercised, as opposed to the problem being that the code isn't doing what you expect.